# C# strip attributes of elements

Tags: c#, security, utility

I've created a strip tag method that will only allow elements that you explicitly allow.   I've been trying to figure out how to do the same with attributes.

I have found a some examples of how to remove specific attributes either by Regex or with [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  however, I'm trying to create something that strips out all attributes except the ones you define (like my method below)

I'm only seeing trees at the moment >*< Sorry if this topic is too wide open >*<  also all my examples...yeah. *shame*. Can I have some help being pointed in the correct direction?

**Examples of the strip tag**

```
string exampleOneWithAllStripped = StripTag("<br />this is an <b>example</b>", null);

string exampleTwoWithOnlyBoldAllowed = StripTag("<br />this is an <b>example</b>", "b");

string exampleThreeWithBRandBoldAllowed = StripTag("<br />this is an <b>example</b>", "b,<br>");

    /// <summary>
    ///     HTML and other mark up tags stripped from a given the string ListOfAllowedTags.
    ///     This Method is the ASP.NET Version of the PHP Strip_Tags Method. It will strip out all html and xml tags
    ///     except for the ones explicitly allowed in the second parameter.  If allowed, this method DOES NOT strip out
    ///     attributes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="htmlString">
    ///     The HTML string.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="listOfAllowedTags">
    ///     The list of allowed tags.  if null, then nothing allowed.  otherwise, ex: "b,<br/>,<hr>,p,i,<u>"
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     Cleaned String
    /// </returns>
    /// <author>James R.</author>
    /// <createdate>10-27-2011</createdate>
    public static string StripTag(string htmlString, string listOfAllowedTags)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlString))
        {
            return htmlString;
        }

        // this is the reg pattern that will retrieve all tags
        string patternThatGetsAllTags = "</?[^><]+>";

        // Create the Regex for all of the Allowed Tags
        string patternForTagsThatAreAllowed = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listOfAllowedTags))
        {
            // get the HTML starting tag, such as p,i,b from an example string of <p>,<i>,<b>
            Regex remove = new Regex("[<>\\/ ]+");

            // now strip out /\<> and spaces
            listOfAllowedTags = remove.Replace(listOfAllowedTags, string.Empty);

            // split at the commas
            string[] listOfAllowedTagsArray = listOfAllowedTags.Split(',');

            foreach (string allowedTag in listOfAllowedTagsArray)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(allowedTag))
                {
                    // jump to next element of array.
                    continue;
                }

                string patternVersion1 = "<" + allowedTag + ">"; // <p>
                string patternVersion2 = "<" + allowedTag + " [^><]*>$";

                // <img src=stuff  or <hr style="width:50%;" />
                string patternVersion3 = "</" + allowedTag + ">"; // closing tag

                // if it is not the first time, then add the pipe | to the end of the string
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(patternForTagsThatAreAllowed))
                {
                    patternForTagsThatAreAllowed += "|";
                }

                patternForTagsThatAreAllowed += patternVersion1 + "|" + patternVersion2 + "|" + patternVersion3;
            }
        }

        // Get all html tags included in the string
        Regex regexHtmlTag = new Regex(patternThatGetsAllTags);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(patternForTagsThatAreAllowed))
        {
            MatchCollection allTagsThatMatched = regexHtmlTag.Matches(htmlString);

            foreach (Match theTag in allTagsThatMatched)
            {
                Regex regOfAllowedTag = new Regex(patternForTagsThatAreAllowed);
                Match matchOfTag = regOfAllowedTag.Match(theTag.Value);

                if (!matchOfTag.Success)
                {
                    // if not allowed replace it with nothing
                    htmlString = htmlString.Replace(theTag.Value, string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // else strip out all tags
            htmlString = regexHtmlTag.Replace(htmlString, string.Empty);
        }

        return htmlString;
    }
```